# C# creating a form for given size

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a rectangle on the screen. I guess the most appropriate way is use a form without boarder.

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
frm.Location = new Point(GlobalPosX, GlobalPosY);
frm.Size = new Size(101, 30);
frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
frm.Show();
```

The created from is not as the given size. It's size is similar to the window having boarder. The displayed window is bit larger as I given and the position is also moved little bit upper and left.
Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ClientSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2.aspx) property instead of `Size`:

```
frm.ClientSize = new Size(101,30);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not the solution. Actually it was fixed after changing the Minimum Size property.

Comment: I fixed it after changing the defaults values (0,0) of the Property MinimumSize. Once you change the minimum size, you can change the size to the window as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw rectangle on the screen, you can draw it directly: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/263740-draw-directly-screen

Answer (score 0):

[Drawing C# graphics without using Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425033/c-graphics-without-windows-form)

That like talks about making a border-less window.  From there, just use the Graphics object to draw whatever you'd like